# Changing java-doc parameter name

Tags: java, eclipse, parameters, javadoc, param

In eclipse: Is there a way to change java-doc's parameter name into something other than the name of the used parameter.

```
/**
  * @param random
  */
 public void doStuff(Random r){ 
 }
```

In the code above I didn't want to use the word "random" as a parameter(for some reason) But I prefer java-doc to show it as random instead of r. When I add change the word in java doc this is the result

```
Parameters:
           random  
           r
```

How can I make java doc omit the original parameter name "r"?

Note: I'm aware that using "r" instead of "random" in method is not a good idea. But this is just an example.

Comment: I'm struggling to think of **any** situation where this is a good idea. Can you suggest one? The whole point of including the parameter name is so that people know which parameter you are talking about.

Comment: @Duncan En example: People are not even supposed to see the method body. If I already have a class member that is named random that I need to use often in method body I need to use this.random constantly. Giving r to parameter name makes it easier to code. Besides when there are multiple parameters eclipse's hovering over feature does not make a good job of showing parameter names. It is easier to just read java doc parameter.

Comment: @Duncan another example: Right now I have a method that uses r instead of random. I will either change javadoc name or change the name of every instance of the parameter.

Comment: Those don't seem like valid reasons. In the first example, there is nothing confusing about having a variable `r` in the Javadoc; so just call it `r` and be done with it. If you need to change `r` to `random` (as per your second example), simply use Eclipse's refactoring features (Alt-Shift-c) - it will change it in the method signature, body and in the Javadoc.